# VSCode extension api – file type/extension icons using ThemeIcon

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, vscode-extensions

We are building an extension that visualizes some data for workspace files in our view using a class derived from `TreeDataProvider`. We wonder if there is a way to use file icons contributed by the current File Icons Theme for our custom tree items. Base icon class has a field `icon: ThemeIcon` which supports product icons. Wonder if something similar exists for referring to file-type icons?

Thanks

Comment: if you use an URI as tree item you get the current file icon

Answer (score 3):

Seems like using `resourceUri` and `ThemeIcon.File` is the way to do it:

```ts
this.iconPath = ThemeIcon.File;
this.resourceUri = Uri.parse('_.js');
```